# How to load WKWebview go to root page when press active tab bar?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, wkwebview

I am a newbie in iOS development using Xcode 10.2 & Swift 5 (Latest update). I'm developing iOS app using TabBar and WKWebview. The application has 5 tabs, each displaying a different web page.

I want to make user experience that when user access the first tab and browse there, then user press another tab bar, after that user back to the first tab and still displaying the same page before go to another tab. If user want to go back to root page of tab, just press again the active tab bar.

How can I make it happen?

I'm using RootViewController then extends to 5 another ViewController:

- HomeViewController

- SignalViewController

- ContactViewController

- NewsViewController

- ProfileViewController

I've tried some suggestions from many sites but failed, such as using:

- UITabBarControllerDelegate tabBarController(*:didSelect:)

- UIViewController viewDidAppear(*:)

- UIViewController viewWillAppear(*:)

- super.viewDidLoad() or self.viewDidLoad()

- UIView setNeedsDisplay(*:)

- webview.load()

```
// set global variable for checking selected index tab
var prevTab: Int = 0
var currentTab: Int = 0;

class RootViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    // declare var for WebKit
    var webView: WKWebView!

    // load view of WebKit
    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    // for display URL in WebKit
    func goToUrl(url: String){
        let myURL = URL(string:url)
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }
}
```

```
class HomeViewController: RootViewController {

    let defaultUrl : String = "https://yourdomain.com/"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // for checking click on active tab to root page of tab
        self.tabBarController?.delegate = self

        // call URL to dipslayed on WebKit View
        self.goToUrl(url: defaultUrl)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // Tells the delegate that the user selected an item in the tab bar
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController){

        // get selected index tab
        currentTab = self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex ?? 0

        if(prevTab == currentTab){
            // MUST GO TO DEFAULT URL
        }

        // save selected index tab for next checking
        prevTab = currentTab
    }

}
```

I expect when user press ACTIVE tab bar again (prevTab is equal to currentTab) then WKWebview goes to default URL, but it fails (nothing happened).

Comment: Can you explain `but it fails` means? Where it gets failed or what's your expected behaviour? Or more precisely can you add your different screenshots?

Comment: "but it fails" means the app is failed to go to default URL. My expectation is when user press ACTIVE tab bar again, wkwebview go to default URL.

Comment: Remove `self.goToUrl(url: defaultUrl)` from `viewDidLoad()` and add inside `viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)`. It will be refreshed whenever you switch `Tabs`

Comment: No, I don't want to refresh tab whenever user switches Tabs. The tab refreshed only when user press the ACTIVE tab again. Example: user access the first tab and browsing there to another webpage "Our Services" from webpage "Home". Then user want to go back to "Home", so user just press the first tab (ACTIVE tab) then WKWebview go to Default URL again.

Comment: You have to load default url on `different` `Tabs` again because in `TabViewController` it wont re-create ViewController if it's already loaded.

Comment: Could we just load default URL in existing WKWebview - ViewController? Or destroy the existing ViewController then re-create ViewController?

Answer (score -1):

According to posted question so far I understand you need properly implement below functions with .   `UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate`.

````
1) ```override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
self.delegate = self
self.tabBarController?.delegate = self
} ```

2) ```override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated) 
} ```

3) ``` override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) { switch item.title! {
case "First":
print("First")
case "Second":
print("Second")
default:
print("Home")
self.selectedIndex = 2 .  /// selection of Tabbar item
}
} ```
````